# Are you able to use conditional formatting on access records as a whole? Changing the entire record color based on one parameter?

Tags: ms-access, conditional-formatting

I am looking to highlight orders based on whether the order has arrived or not. Ex. arrived would highlight the entire record green whereas issue would highlight the entire record red.

The form i am using is a datasheet form. I am confused whether adding a text box would be beneficial but i cannot imagine how that would be presented.

I have tried using conditional formatting but I am unable to use multiple rules. I can go in manually and edit each field but this seems like a silly way to do this. I am only able to color the whole row in reports but i would like my info presented like a datasheet.

Only the id color is changing as I manually put rules in regarding the status of the order. I would like the entire record to change.

Comment: Only textboxes and comboboxes can have CF. Use a textbox stretched full length of record behind other controls set as transparent. Set CF on that textbox.

Comment: How would i place a text box in a datasheet form? Just overlay all the text over the boxes in design mode?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the point about datasheet mode. Form would have to be Continuous or Single for this approach. So even labels on each record would appear to show the color. Don't really follow what you meant by "go in manually and edit each field".

Comment: As in a user would go in and update the status of an order. And then based off what they put in that fields, the entire record would change color. I just wanted to essentially highlight a line as you would in ms excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the work around. You cannot select multiple fields in datasheet view but in design view you can select multiple text boxes and apply the conditional formatting to change the whole row.

Comment: That's not really a work around. That is exactly how CF is supposed to be set up - in design view. Exactly what else were you doing?

Comment: I was trying to select multiple fields from the datasheet view as this is how i wanted to display the information. However, I found out that you must can multi select fields in design view and apply CF and change the view back to datasheet and the rules will apply to multiple fields.